# std::visit does not recognise types

Tags: c++, lambda, generic-lambda, std-variant

I'm stumped that after some code refactoring, the following piece of code does not work anymore as in it jumps to the `auto, auto` case and ignores the `Complex, Complex` one. I admittedly don't quite understand what the [overload](https://arne-mertz.de/2018/05/overload-build-a-variant-visitor-on-the-fly/) is *exactly* doing, but to me, the two codes look exactly the same, with the exception, that one gets its parameters directly whereas the other one has the parameters defined in the function body itself.

```
Math_Node Function_Manager::add(const Math_Node& arg){
        Math_Object obj1 = arg.children_ptr()->at(0)->data();
        Math_Object obj2 = arg.children_ptr()->at(1)->data();
        if( std::holds_alternative<Complex>(obj1) ){
            std::cerr << "obj1 is complex\n";
        }
        if( std::holds_alternative<Complex>(obj2) ){
            std::cerr << "obj2 is complex\n";
        }
        return std::visit(overload{
               [](const Complex& a, const Complex& b) -> Math_Object{ 
                   std::cerr << "COMPLEX ADD_\n"; 
                   return add_(a, b); 
               }
             , [](const Matrix& a, const Matrix& b) -> Math_Object{ 
                   std::cerr << "MATRIX ADD_\n"; 
                   return add_(a, b); 
               }
             , [&arg](auto& a, auto& b) -> Math_Node{
                   std::cerr << "NOT FOUND\n"; 
                   return arg;
             }
         }, obj1, obj2);
}
```

The code prints

```
obj1 is complex
obj2 is complex
NOT FOUND
```

This was the working code before refactoring:

```
Math_Object Function_Manager::add(const Math_Object& arg0, const Math_Object& arg1){
        return
                std::visit(
                        overload{
                                [](const Complex& a, const Complex& b) -> Math_Object{ return add_(a, b); }
                                , [](const Matrix& a, const Matrix& b) -> Math_Object{ return add_(a, b); }
                                , [](auto& a, auto& b) -> Math_Object{
                                    throw std::runtime_error(
                                            ("Unsupported arguments for add: " + to_string(a) + to_string(b)).c_str());
                                }
                        }, arg0, arg1
                          );
    }
```

The only thing I could come up with was that `obj1` and `obj2` are not really of the desired types, but the print to `std::cerr` proves that they are. So why does std::visit not recognise it as such and **how can I fix it?**

Comment: `auto&` is preferred to `T const&` for a non-const `T`. Try changing `auto&` to `auto const&`.

Comment: Then I get an invalid conversion error.

Comment: @infinitezero Could you please add that error message to your question? I don't see why there should be an error.

Comment: It's insanely long. Math_Object is an std::variant which contains Complex. Math_Node is a templated Node, where the template is set to Math_Object. By changing the return type of the lambda to Math_Node instead of returning Math_Object, which calls the Math_Node constructor implicitly, I got rid of the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example `obj1` and `obj2` are not `const` qualified.

In your second example `arg0` and `arg1` are.

`overload` simply does overload resolution on the call operators of all the lambdas given to it (assuming it is the usual implementation).

---

In overload resolution for the first example `auto&`/`auto&` is a better match for `obj1`/`obj2` than `const Complex&`/`const Complex&`, because the latter requires a qualification conversion to add the `const`, while `auto&`/`auto&` can be deduced to `Complex&`/`Complex&`, which does not require a qualification conversion.

---

This is not the case in the second example, since `arg0`/`arg1` are `const`, the template argument deduction for `auto&`/`auto&` will yield `const Complex&`/`const Complex&` and neither this call nor the one taking `const Complex&`/`const Complex&` directly will need any conversions.

If two functions have equally good conversion sequences for a call, then the call is disambiguated by a few additional criteria, one of which is that non-template functions are preferred to template functions. The overload taking `const Complex&`/`const Complex&` directly is not a template (since it is not a generic lambda) and so it is preferred.

---

To resolve this, just take the same qualifications in all calls, i.e. take `const auto&`/`const auto&` instead of `auto&`/`auto&` in the last call or reproduce the second example's overload resolution behavior by passing `std::as_const(obj1)` and `std::as_const(obj2)` instead of `obj1` and `obj2` to `std::visit`.

Comment: Oh wow, yes it seems obvious now. Thanks. At first I got an invalid conversion error that I could fix by explicit casting!

Comment: @infinitezero I am not sure what that error would be and why a cast is needed anywhere. Could you add that to your question? Instead of explicit casting or changing the `auto` parameters, you could pass `obj1` and `obj2` via `std::as_const` to `std::visit` to obtain the second examples behavior. I don't see any reason for casts here and explicit casts tend to be dangerous, especially if they cast `const` *away*.